# Using image() in R: How to left-align tick marks on x-axis?

Tags: r, image, axis

I am making a two-color figure from a data table consisting of rows of 0's and 1's, like this:

```
mem/Bur_05_sorted.bam_A 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
mem/Bur_05_sorted.bam_B 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
mem/Ell_06_sorted.bam_A 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
mem/Ell_06_sorted.bam_B 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
mem/Ell_07_sorted.bam_A 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
mem/Ell_07_sorted.bam_B 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
mem/Ste_01_sorted.bam_A 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
mem/Ste_01_sorted.bam_B 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
mem/Sto_02_sorted.bam_A 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
mem/Sto_02_sorted.bam_B 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
mem/Sto_03_sorted.bam_A 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
mem/Sto_03_sorted.bam_B 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
mem/Sto_07_sorted.bam_A 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
mem/Sto_07_sorted.bam_B 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
mem/Vog_01_sorted.bam_A 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
mem/Vog_01_sorted.bam_B 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
mem/Vog_02_sorted.bam_A 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
mem/Vog_02_sorted.bam_B 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
mem/Vog_03_sorted.bam_A 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
mem/Vog_03_sorted.bam_B 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
mem/Vog_04_sorted.bam_A 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
mem/Vog_04_sorted.bam_B 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
mem/Vog_05_sorted.bam_A 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
mem/Vog_05_sorted.bam_B 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
mem/Vog_06_sorted.bam_A 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
mem/Vog_06_sorted.bam_B 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Using this code:

```
a<-read.table("L_1616.vit.txt",row.names=1)

rowlabs = c("Bur_05_A","Bur_05_B","Ell_06_A","Ell_06_B","Ell_07_A","Ell_07_B","Ste_01_A","Ste_01_B","Sto_02_A","Sto_02_B","Sto_03_A","Sto_03_B","Sto_07_A","Sto_07_B","Vog_01_A","Vog_01_B","Vog_02_A","Vog_02_B","Vog_03_A","Vog_03_B","Vog_04_A","Vog_04_B","Vog_05_A","Vog_05_B","Vog_06_A","Vog_06_B")

columnlabs = c(0:(ncol(a)-1))*0.25

x11()
par(mar=c(5,6,4,2)+.1)
image(t(as.matrix(a)),col=c("blue","red"),axes=F)
axis(1,at=seq(0,2,length.out=ncol(a)), labels=columnlabs,las=2)
axis(2,at=seq(1,0,length.out=nrow(a)), labels=rowlabs, las=1)
savePlot("./plots/L_1616.png","png")
```

In the figure, the tick marks are centered for each "block".
[image]

However, I'd like the tick marks to align to the left center of each "block". Like this:
[image]

How can I achieve this? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the 'at' positions in your `axis(1,...)` call, which determine where the tick marks are placed.
By default, `image()` draws each block centred on equally-spaced values from 0 to 1, so the width of each block is 1/n if there are n blocks across the image.  So you need to generate a series of 'at' positions that are offset by 1/2n to the left.

```
data=matrix(sample(1:2,192,replace=T),ncol=16)
image(data,axes=F)
x_tick_offset=1/(2*nrow(data))
y_tick_offset=1/(2*ncol(data))
axis(1,at=seq(0,1,length.out=nrow(data))-x_tick_offset,labels=letters[1:nrow(data)])
axis(2,at=seq(1,0,length.out=ncol(data))+y_tick_offset,labels=1:ncol(data),las=2)
```